# Python - Delete column from a matrix without numPy

Tags: python

this is my first question on here. The question is simple -

```
# this removes the top list from the list of lists
triangle = [
[3, 0, 0],
[2, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0]]
del triangle[0]
```

I want to have a similarly easy way to remove a 'column'. I can of course do this using a for loop, but is there something equivalent to

```
del triangle[0]
```

Thankyou

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to do this *in place* without copying the whole list, then something like

```
all(map(lambda x: x.pop(which_column), triangle))
```

EDIT. yes, it won't work if there's 0 in the column, just use any other accumulator function

```
sum(map(lambda x: x.pop(which_column), triangle))
```

for python 2 where `map` is not an iterator accumulator is not needed:

```
map(lambda x: x.pop(1), triangle)
```

as a side effect, this returns the deleted column which you may use

```
deleted_column = list(map(lambda x: x.pop(which_column), triangle))
```

(for python 2 list() wrapper is not needed)

A shorter form would be

```
sum(i.pop(which_column) for i in triangle)
```

or

```
deleted_column = [i.pop(which_column) for i in triangle]
```

Although I'm not sure if it qualifies as 'without for loop'

P.S. In official Python documentation they use 0-lenqth deque to consume iterators, like this:

```
collections.deque(map(lambda x: x.pop(which_column), triangle), maxlen=0)
```

I don't know if it's better than sum(), but it can be used for non-numeric data

Comment: This is actually the best option, not just because it accomplishes the task in one line.

Raymond Hettinger's first method in fact modifies 'triangle' so it is no longer a list of lists and becomes a tuple (I may be saying some of this wrong as I am a fairly new user). Thereupon resulting in an error if the same procedure is performed on 'triangle' again.

panda-34's code produces no such errors

Comment: I like the terseness, but this won't work correctly. As soon as it hits a 0 value in the column, it stops removing elements.

Comment: Really? I'm actually using it to remove 0s and it's doing the job.

Comment: @BenLucato, if it works for 0s for you, that means that map is not an iterator (in python 2 it wasn't (??)) in that case you don't need all() or sum() wrapper at all.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use [*zip()*](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) to transpose the matrix, delete the target row, and then zip it back:

```
>>> def delcolumn(mat, i):
        m = zip(*mat)
        del m[i]
        return zip(*m)

>>> triangle = delcolumn(triangle, 1)
>>> pprint(triangle, width=20)
[(3, 0),
 (2, 0),
 (1, 0)]
```

Another way is to use [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation):

```
>>> def delcolumn(mat, i):
        return [row[:i] + row[i+1:] for row in mat]

>>> triangle = delcolumn(triangle, 1)
>>> pprint(triangle, width=20)
[(3, 0),
 (2, 0),
 (1, 0)]
```

One last technique is to mutate the matrix in-place using *del*:

```
>>> def delcolumn(mat, i):
         for row in mat:
             del row[i]
```

Comment: Thankyou - though having something like triangle[:][0] to specify a column would still be the best - this is definitely right behind it.

Comment: Note, however, that using a loop will be around twice as fast - http://pastebin.com/551BJ9Jx